# Add json Values to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object with the following structure ...

```
[{
    "staffId": 4,
    "forename": "Testf",
    "surname": "Tests",
    "location": "Testl",
    "phoneNumber": "00000000000",
    "email": "Teste"
}, {
    "staffId": 20,
    "forename": "Testf",
    "surname": "Tests",
    "location": "Testl",
    "phoneNumber": "00000000000",
    "email": "Teste"
}]
```

Can anyone advise how I would convert the following to a nested array, with a structure like the following ...

```
var arr = [
    [4, "Testf", "Tests", "Testl", "00000000000", "Teste"],
    [20, "Testf", "Tests", "Testl", "00000000000", "Teste"]
]
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641005/how-can-i-remove-key-name-from-json-object-in-key-value-pair/34641211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. Hope this will help you.

```
var item = [
            { "staffId": 4, "forename": "Testf", "surname": "Tests", "location": "Testl", "phoneNumber": "00000000000", "email": "Teste" }, 
            { "staffId": 20, "forename": "Testf", "surname": "Tests", "location": "Testl", "phoneNumber": "00000000000", "email": "Teste" }
           ];

var final=[];
$.each(item, function () {
    var arr=[];
    for (var prop in this) {
        arr.push(this[prop]);
    }
    final.push(arr);
})

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```js
var input = [{"staffId":4,"forename":"Testf","surname":"Tests","location":"Testl","phoneNumber":"00000000000","email":"Teste"},{"staffId":20,"forename":"Testf","surname":"Tests","location":"Testl","phoneNumber":"00000000000","email":"Teste"}];
var output = input.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  }); 
});
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

While objects does not have an order, i suggest to use an array constant for the keys and iterate over it.

```js
var array = [{ "staffId": 4, "forename": "Testf", "surname": "Tests", "location": "Testl", "phoneNumber": "00000000000", "email": "Teste" }, { "staffId": 20, "forename": "Testf", "surname": "Tests", "location": "Testl", "phoneNumber": "00000000000", "email": "Teste" }],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return ['staffId', 'forename', 'surname', 'location', 'phoneNumber'].map(function (b) {
            return a[b];
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```